# SQL for filter records based on another query on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with following columns

1. TrialId
2. Points
3. TrialDateTime
4. UserId

This represents trials done by a user & the points he scored in the trial.
A particular user may do 10 trials so he may have 10 records in the table.

I want to get all records where points are greated than 50, but only if that trial represents the 4th or more trial of that particular user. The number of a particular trial is not represented in the table. However, if a userid has 5 trials, then the datetime field can be used to figure out which is the first/second etc.

So basically I want to get all trials where the score is greater 50 & the same userid has 3 other other trials in the table which has a lesser datetime.

Is there a way to do this via SQL?

I know that I can get

```
select * from tbl where points > 50;
```

will get me all records where points > 50, but how do I filter it further?

If I had the datetime of a particular record in a variable called X, I could do

```
select count(TrialId) from tbl where TrialDateTime > 'somedatetime' and userid = 'someuid'.
```

to check if there are more than 3 older records for the same userid. But is there a way to combine both of this using SQL? What other options do I have?

Sample records

```
1. T1, 20, 2013-05-09 14:10:27.000, U1
2. T2, 40, 2013-05-09 14:20:27.000, U1
3. T3, 45, 2013-05-09 14:30:27.000, U1
4. T4, 60, 2013-05-09 14:40:27.000, U1
5. T5, 20, 2013-05-09 12:11:27.000, U2
6. T6, 30, 2013-05-09 12:12:27.000, U2
7. T7, 60, 2013-05-09 12:13:27.000, U2
8. T8, 40, 2013-05-09 12:54:27.000, U2
```

Here Record 4 will be selected. However, Record 7 will not be selected though both have scores above 50.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Which sql-server version are you using?

Comment: @JW웃 - added sample records.

Comment: @Arion - Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.UserId 
                          ORDER BY t.TrialDateTime) AS NbrOfTrails,
        t.*
    FROM 
        tbl AS t
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.NbrOfTrails > 3
    AND CTE.Points > 50
```

References:

[Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Does this have any dependency on SQL Server 2008? i.e. will it work on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: @user93353 : I have updated the answer with some references. If you read the link you will see that it has no dependencies to 2008. It will work in 2005 as well

Comment: Thank you. I asked only because in the comments you asked me what version of SQL Server I was using. Anyway, I understood how your query works - I didn't even know these kinds of things were possible in SQL - ROW_NUMBER, Partition & With. My knowledge of SQL is basic at best. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user93353 : I asked because if you would use mssql 2000. Then these functions are not available. I know that the likenesses is slim. But I just have to be certain. But I am glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can do the following:

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        tbl as outertable
    WHERE
        points > 50 AND
        (
            SELECT
                    COUNT(*) AS Number
                FROM
                    tbl as innertable
                WHERE
                    innertable.UserID = outertable.UserID AND
                    innertable.TrialDateTime < outertable.TrialDateTime
        ) > 2
```